# Parse either fixed offset or Area/Location timezone

Tags: datetime, rust, rust-chrono

Here's my `src/main.rs` file:

```rust
use chrono_tz::Tz;

fn parse_ts(ts: &str) -> Tz {
    ts.parse().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let ts: &str = "UTC";
    println!("parsed: {:?}", parse_ts(ts));
}
```

It runs fine! But if I replace `"UTC"` with `"+00:00"`, then it errors:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "'+00:00' is not a valid timezone"', src/main.rs:4:16
```

Can I rewrite it such that `parse_ts` can handle both fixed offsets and `'Area/Location'` timezones?

Comment: I doubt there is a ready to use function since "+00:00" can mean at least 2 different time zones and the hour difference generally is ambiguous especially with daylight savings times all around the wolrd.

Comment: it's it just UTC+0, which isn't ambiguous?

Comment: Ok "+00:00" isn't the best example but is "+01:00" supposed to become BST or CET, ...

Comment: fixed offset of 1 hour - UTC+1

Comment: Another contender, so even more ambiguity...

Comment: in my application, I know that it means "fixed offset of 1 hour" - is there a way to return that as a `Tz`?